# Facebook Groups App

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking for an alternative to the Facebook groups app that supports categories (like Google+ groups do)

Vital:

- Support categories
- App must be a Facebook app
- Notifications when a new topic is posted or when someone replies to one of your posts
- Discussion area for posting/liking
- Ability to create private groups

Nice to have:

- Ability to appear in sidebar
- Support for events
- Schemed to look like a native part of Facebook
- Support for only receiving notifications for particular categories

Comment: You're asking a feature that isn't implemented in Facebook. How would you create group categories if Facebook doesn't have this option?

Comment: These guys seems to be building something that would help ( at least on the monitoring side ): [http://facebucket.io/](http://facebucket.io/)